# tableView with prototype cell not reloading data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hey Guys I'm trying of figure out what i'm doing wrong with no luck

basically I have a webservice that returns some results that I want to put them in table in an iOS app

I am using prototype cell with 3 labels do put the results per line of the table

The problem is that the table is always empty

I checked that no values regarding the web service response are nil

Can anyone Help Me?

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class DetailsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var TableDeliveryDetails: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bostampLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var distribuidorLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var exploracaoLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dataLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descargaLabel: UILabel!


    var bostampLabelText=""
    var distribuidorLabelText=""
    var exploracaoLabelText=""
    var dataLabelText=""
    var descargaLabelText=""
    var getsDetailsCollection = [GetDeliveryDetailsClass]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.TableDeliveryDetails.dataSource=self
        self.TableDeliveryDetails.delegate=self
        self.TableDeliveryDetails.registerClass(TableViewCellDetails.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")


        //bostampLabel.text=bostampLabelText
        distribuidorLabel.text=distribuidorLabelText
        exploracaoLabel.text=exploracaoLabelText
        dataLabel.text=dataLabelText
        descargaLabel.text=descargaLabelText


        Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://192.168.0.1:1278/api/Delivery/GetDeliveryDetais", parameters: ["stamp": bostampLabelText])
            .responseJSON { response in
                print(response.request)  // original URL request
                print(response.response) // URL response
                print(response.data)     // server data
                print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

                if let JSON = response.result.value {

                    let jsonResults = JSON as! NSArray
                    for var i = 0; i < jsonResults.count; i++ {
                        var produto=jsonResults[i]["Produto"] as! String
                        var qttKg = jsonResults[i]["QuantidadeKG"] as! Double
                        var qttLt = jsonResults[i]["QuantidadeLT"] as! Double
                        var getObj = GetDeliveryDetailsClass(produto:produto,qttKg:qttKg,qttLt:qttLt)

                        self.getsDetailsCollection.append(getObj)
                        // print(add)
                        // TableClienteFinal.append(add)
                    }

                }
                self.reload_table_data()

        }


    }

    func reload_table_data()
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            self.TableDeliveryDetails.reloadData()
            return
            })
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.getsDetailsCollection.count
    }

     func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



      //  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCellDetails
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! TableViewCellDetails

        let object = self.getsDetailsCollection[indexPath.row]
        cell.columProdutoText=object.produto
        cell.columQttKgText=String(format:"%f", object.qttKg)
        cell.columnQttLtText=String(format:"%f", object.qttLt)
        return cell
    }
```

Anyone???

Comment: Check if `self.getsDetailsCollection.count` is greater than 0. If it's greater than 0 try printing the values stored in `self.getsDetailsCollection ` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` before setting the labels.

Comment: Both self.getsDetailsCollection.count and self.getsDetailsCollection are not empty or nil

Comment: can you show TableViewCellDetails declaration

Comment: `class TableViewCellDetails: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var columProduto: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var columQttKg: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var columnQttLt: UILabel!
    var columProdutoText=""
    var columQttKgText=""
    var columnQttLtText=""
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        columProduto.text=columProdutoText
        columQttKg.text=columQttKgText
        columnQttLt.text=columnQttLtText
    }
    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}`

Comment: self.TableDeliveryDetails.registerClass(TableViewCellDetails.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

Answer (score 0):

Use this

> cell.columProdutoText.text=object.produto
>   cell.columQttKgText.text=String(format:"%f", object.qttKg)
>   cell.columnQttLtText.text=String(format:"%f", object.qttLt)

If columProdutoText , cloumQttKgText ,columnQttLtText are labels having outlets in your customtableviewcell

Comment: Yes they are labels, If I do that i get the following error: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Ok , then please provide the code of GetDeliveryDetailsClass once .

Comment: What do you mean provide it once?

Comment: I mean post its code here ..so that i can have a look if everything is fine in it

Comment: It's just a simple class: _italic_ **bold** `import Foundation

class GetDeliveryDetailsClass{
    var produto:String
    var qttKg:Double
    var qttLt:Double
    
    init(produto:String,qttKg:Double,qttLt:Double) {
        self.produto = produto
        self.qttKg = qttKg
        self.qttLt = qttLt
    }
    
    
}`

Answer (score 0):

Weird question for me to ask but did you also set the datasource and delegate in your storyboard file? I've seen that every time I just set the delegate and datasource in code it never linked up in IB so my cells were always empty. Once I linked them in IB I was fine

Comment: I did it both ways...first in code then in storyboard